# How to add 2 (onclick)=" " for one Input Radio Button in Angular -5

Tags: angular, html

I Have 4 Components in Angular 5.
In first component I have 3 radio buttons,
if we click on radio button each will take to other components by (click)= " " ,
but radio button not getting checked, so how can navigate to other component and radio button will checked at a time, if I click on radio button?

```
<div class="form-group row form-bg">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Type </label>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <label class="radio-inline" style="color: #fd6428; font-weight: bold;">
            <input type="radio"  name="stock" (click)="stock()"> Stock 
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
           <input type="radio" name="nonStock"  (click)="nonStock()" > Non-Stock
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="equipment"  (click)="equipment()"  > Equipment
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="exchange" (click)="exchange()"  > Exchange
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="loan" (click)="loan()" > Loan
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

.ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-item-master-setup',
    templateUrl: './item-master-setup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./item-master-setup.component.scss']
})

/** item-master-setup component*/

export class ItemMaster {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    stock()
    {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/itemmastersmodule/itemmasterpages/app-item-master-stock');
    }

    nonStock()
    {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/itemmastersmodule/itemmasterpages/app-item-master-non-stock');
    }

    equipment() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/itemmastersmodule/itemmasterpages/app-item-master-equipment');
    }

    exchange() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/itemmastersmodule/itemmasterpages/app-item-master-exchange');
    }

    loan() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/itemmastersmodule/itemmasterpages/app-item-master-loan');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From whatever I could understand from your code:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="stock" (click)="doSomething()" >
```

TS:

```
    doSomething() {
            setInterval(() => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('url');
            }, 100);
        }
```

Ideally the selection on the radio button should persist if you are just changing the view of just one part of the page and the radio buttons are in another part. 
Meaning your router-outlet should be placed separately from your radio button component.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you should re-config you routes.
And put on a "router-outlet" tag under your radio button
Then let the router-outlet decides which component to render depend on the radio button that you clicked.
Look for me here in official page [Router outlet](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet)

```
<div class="form-group row form-bg">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Type </label>
     <div class="col-sm">
       <label class="radio-inline" style="color: #fd6428; font-weight: bold;">
        <input type="radio"  name="stock" (click)="stock()"> Stock 
       </label>
       ......
     </div>
 </div>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I assume that this html of your will be the template of `MasterPageComponent`
Your routes:

```
{
 path: 'itemmastersmodule',
 children: [
  {
    path: 'itemmasterpages',
    component:  MasterPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'app-item-master-stock',
        component: ItemMasterStockPageComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'app-item-master-non-stock',
        component: ItemMasterNonStockPageComponent,
      },
      ....
    ],
  },
 ],
},
```

Although you don't have to create 4 separate components, you can use same component with different type of list and config it in router like this

```
{
 path: 'itemmastersmodule',
 children: [
  {
    path: 'itemmasterpages/:type',
    component:  MasterPageComponent,
  },
 ],
},
```

and your component could be for example ItemMasterPageComponent
You can look for more [HERE](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/v/v2.3/handout/routing/routeparams.html)

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params : any) => {
  this.type = params.type;
  this.itemMasterService.getItemsByType(this.type);
});
```